# Authorized App prompting with wrong App by Google OAuth login

Tags: android, ios, oauth

I am trying to use OAuth for Google+ login in my App, the flow working perfectly but the issue facing is very strange.

Native App created
Client ID: My client ID
Secrect: My secrect ID

Google+ button to OAuth request token
LOgin page
Authorize or Grant (below image) have display wrong App.

[image]

In Google console project I have another client for this App also and this will be used in iOS. For Android OAuth I am using Native client id to obtain Access and Refresh token.

I am stuck here

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, actually I created single project under Google Console in that I have set details  -> **APIs & AUth** -> **Consent Screen** and create Client ID under this project that's why it will displaying this project name instead of What I want for another App.

For this type of things need to create separate project in you account and create Client ID or Keys for respective project.

Hope this will help to other.